# Why is it not connecting to my database? Java JBDC,

Tags: java, jdbc

The error is "Exception: invalid database address: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library?user=root&password=myPassword" 
I am using a MySQL database and am a beginner at this, so I'm a bit confused. The name of my database in MySQL is "library"....so can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
import java.sql.*;
public class connectToMySQL {


public static void main(String[] args) {
     Connection con = null;
        try {

          con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library?user=root&password=myPassword");
          System.out.println("Connected with the database!");

}
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());

}
}
}
```

Comment: You need to register your database driver. Something like `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

Comment: @user1875195 Not since 2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't a valid database url. Change this

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library?user=root&password=myPassword");
```

to use [`DriverManager.getConnection(String, String, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). Something like

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library", "root", "myPassword");
```

Also, you could use a [`try-with-resources` close statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Like,

```
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library", "root", "myPassword")) {
```